# Python 3.5 - Compile pygame code with nuitka

Tags: python-3.x, compilation, pygame, nuitka

I want to compile a game I made in Python. I searched around for compilers and I prefer Nuitka because it is cross-platform. But whenever I try to compile my code with Nuitka using `nuitka --recurse-all --standalone myappname.py` I get this error:

```
Cannot find 'pygame' as relative or absolute import.
```

I have pygame installed, could anyone please help me?

PS: I dont want to use "compilers" like cx_freeze

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

first, do: pip install pygame
second: make sure you have a correct import statement on top of your main app module.

Comment: compiling with cxfreeze works, so thats not the problem

Comment: @StamKaly Did you start Nuitka the right way? I mean, on Windows first start Visual C command prompt and then change dir to your app and run Nuitka? Or do you have MinGW instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `--follow-imports` instead of `--recurse-all`. At least for me, that always worked in the past.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).